# Finding an Html Control in c# winform by a webbrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, webbrowser-control

I am writing a `Winform` application that will navigate a web browser control to a specific URL as:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("web.facebook.com");
```

And now I want to get all the `HTML` elements of this page and retrieve values of these controls, after googling and all the stuff I have managed to write this code snippet which shows no error but throws an exception saying:

> Object Reference not set to an instance of object.

```
mshtml.IHTMLInputElement email = (mshtml.IHTMLInputElement)webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("email").DomElement;
MessageBox.Show(email.value);
```

this code snippet is placed in the `Navigated` event of the web browser control. so how am I gonna do that? any Ideas and suggestion are Appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try also **DocumentCompleted** event, and post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) code

Comment: _What_ is causing the NRE?

Comment: @Brian it is because of getting the Html Element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot guys, i figured the way out,, Here is how i did that!

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        mshtml.IHTMLInputElement email = (mshtml.IHTMLInputElement)webFacebook.Document.GetElementById("email").DomElement;
        MessageBox.Show(email.value);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Special Thanks @Eser! :)

Answer (score 2):

Put a breakpoint on the first assignment and figure out which bit is returning a null value:

- `webBrowser1.Document`,
- `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("email")` or
- `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("email").DomElement`

so do something like this:

```
var doc = webBrowser1.Document;
var elem = doc.GetElementById("email");
var email = elem.DomElement;
```

and step through the code.

It might also be worth your while to browse the webBrowser1.Document in the debugger to see that it actually contains what you think it should contain.